# DHCP get wrong ip

Tags: networking, vpn, dhcp

I have ubuntu14.4. recently I faced a problem that I haven't before.
in my university when I want connect to internet, first I should connect to a access point and then connect to the internet through a pptp vpn server.before I faced this problem the access point gave me an ip: 10.15.3.11. now when I connect to the access point, It give me another Ip:192.168.0.127. so I cannot see vpn server and therefore I cannot connect to internet.how can I fix this problem?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably has nothing to do with your Ubuntu install.  It sounds like there are two DHCP servers assigning from different network blocks, and the 192.x.x.x one is incorrect.  So if the "access point" in question is actually your personal router, you'll have to

- disable the DHCP function
- use a LAN port on the router instead of it's WAN port to avoid a double-NAT situation.

If this doesn't solve it, you'll have to describe the network topology much more clearly.

Comment: I just manually set Ip address, Geteway address and DNS address, and now I can connect to internet. but I have no idea why It worked fine earlier and now I have to set my ip manually?

Comment: If my guess is correct and there are two DHCP servers, there is no way to control which one you respond to.  A network should only ever have one DHCP server active on a segment.

Comment: Is it possible that someone else inject a DHCP server to corrupt the network?

Comment: Very possible.  Someone may have plugged a router in, thinking it would be a good access point.  Complain to your sysadmin.